# Node JS HTTP Request/Grab String

Tags: node.js

I need to make a get request to an API that will give me a string that I will then use in my app, however I can't seem to do this easily.

I've done the following but it doesn't work.

```
function updateClients() {
    var jsonData = "";
    request('http://api.com', function (error, response, body) {
      if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        var jsonData = body; 
      }
    });

    console.log(jsonData);
    io.sockets.emit('update', jsonData);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
const http = require('http')
function updateClients() {
   let chunkData = '';
    let request = http.get('http://api.com', function(response) {
        response.on('data', function(chunk) {
            chunkData += chunk;
        });
        response.on('end', function() {
            console.log(chunkData );
            io.sockets.emit('update', chunkData );
        })
    });
    request.on('error', function(error) {
        console.log(error)
    })
    request.end();
  }
```